# Get Date Count from Date Rage compare with Date List in sql

Tags: sql

Sry for the wried title,

Here is the issue :

```
Date From   Date To
01/07/2020  01/07/2020
08/07/2020  10/07/2020


Date List

01/07/2020
02/07/2020
03/07/2020
04/07/2020
05/07/2020
06/07/2020
07/07/2020
08/07/2020
09/07/2020
10/07/2020

Expected Result

Count 4 Day
```

I have two data sources, one is the date from and date to (date range) and another is the date list.

Get date count of date list that inside in date range.(eg. 1,8,9,10 is inside in date range)

First idea is loop the date list and checks this date is exist in from to date.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `join` or `exists`:

```
select count(*)
from datelist dl
where exists (select 1
              from othertable t
              where dt.date >= t.datefrom and dt.date <= t.dateto
             );
```